# How to start debug from command-line in xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I have a xcode project and I edit the source files in Visual Studio, built it by calling *xcodebuild* command from SSH. But when build success I need move to Mac and click the xcode's **RUN** button to start debug, however is there a way to automated run debug from command-line like *xcodebuild* after my build is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you need. xcodebuild doesn't have any way to do the equivalent of pressing the run button (although you could probably write a script that would do that). But the simplest way may be to just start up lldb and run your program through that as you would for any command line debugging session.